# Не применять правило к child-елементам списка

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование

Скажите пожалуйста есть ли способ применить правило ко всем елементам li самого первого ul при этом не касаясь всех вложенных ul списков, т.к. их более 20ти и все со своими классами?

```css
.boss li {
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<ul class="boss">
  <li>I must be strong</li>
  <li>
    I'm boss.
    <ul class="rookie">
      <li>I'm rookie ;)
        <ul class="troll">
          <li>Hi.</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    Text
    <ul class="again">
      <li>Text</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте дочерние селекторы с применением `>`. В таком случае правило будет действовать на элемент, который располагается непосредственно  внутри родительского элемента:

```css
/*правило для только для самых первых li списка ul.boss*/
ul.boss > li {
  font-weight:bold;
}

/*правило для всех, в том числе вложенных li списка ul.boss*/
ul.boss li {
  font-weight:normal;
}
```

```html
<ul class="boss">
  <li>I must be strong</li>
  <li>
    I'm boss.
    <ul class="rookie">
      <li>I'm rookie ;)
        <ul class="troll">
          <li>Hi.</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    Text
    <ul class="again">
      <li>Text</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @kizoso спасибо за правку

Answer (score -1):

```js
var boss = document.querySelector("ul.boss");
boss.firstElementChild.style.fontWeight = "600";
```

```html
<ul class="boss">
  <li>I must be strong</li>
  <li>
    I'm boss.
    <ul class="rookie">
      <li>I'm rookie ;)
        <ul class="troll">
          <li>Hi.</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    Text
    <ul class="again">
      <li>Text</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы благодарен за ваш экспертный комментарий к приведенному выше коду.